# Jboss Fuse 6.2, install custom features to profile in fabric

Tags: apache-karaf, jbossfuse, karaf, fabric8

I was able to do what I'm goin to describe in Fuse 6.1 but now in Fuse 6.2 I get an exception and it is not working anymore.

By following a tutorial, I build a "multi module" project that has a features component in order to install all the needed bundles.

I'm working on a fabric container with a child container.

I create a new profile and then from hawtio console I try to add the feature repository. (BTW I have the same problem if I use the terminal console)

The feature repository is added correctly (that's what fuse says at least) but when I enter the page to add any feature I see this in the log:

> org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not
>   find artifact it.mytria.demo:esercizio1-feature:xml:features:1.0.0 in
>   karaf-default
>   (file:C:/servers/fuse/system/)

Of course, it is right, since I never installed the bundle in that folder, but I have it in my local .m2/repository

Now, the question is, has anyone ever installed a custom feature in Jboss 6.2 and can help me get out from this situation?

The only solution I found is to manually copy the feature and all the custom bundled indicated by the feature in the "/system" folder, but I never had to do this in Fuse 6.1 so I don't like this solution at all.

Other thing, there is a conf file in Fuse 6.2 that has changed from Fuse 6.1, `C:\servers\fuse\etc\io.fabric8.maven.cfg`  and it is the only file I found pointing to the system folder... but I'm afraid that if I add the `.m2` folder here then Fuse will try to search there any bundle even those that has to be really taken from `system` folder.

So far I haven't find any other difference in the config file about maven repository.

There is any good guy out there that know how to make this thing work?

Please, if I missed some important information, let me know, I'll try my best to complete the question.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I installed a clean JbossFuse 6.2.0. Then from the hawtio console I just add the repository to the profile using

> mvn:it.mytria.demo/esercizio1-feature/1.0.0/xml/features

and it worked.

So... I have no idea what went wrong the first time. I made no changes to the projects code or pom configuration of the bundles.